# Mostrar un mensaje de insercion sin flash sessions en laravel 5.2 con controladores restfull

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel y  quiero hacer una inserción en una tabla, y que cuando lo inserte muestre un mensaje en la vista como que el registro ha quedado insertado.

Lo he intentado infinidad de veces con sesiones flash y no hay forma humana de que muestre el mensaje.

Estoy usando controladores restful, y en el método store es en el que intento redireccionar a la vista, como digo he probado con el metodo redirect::to
de este modo

```
Redirect::to('raulpalaciox/')->with('message', 'enviado');
```

pero no me muestra nada.

He probado retornando una vista

```
return view('raulPalacioview.usuario.index',compact('mensajex'));
```

pero al ser controladores restful me lleva a una ruta que no es correcta, ya que el método create y el metodo store comparten la misma ruta.(no se si se puede cambiar esto en alguna parte)
por ultimo he probado con

```
Redirect::route('raulPalacio')
```

y

```
Redirect::route('raulPalacio',array('mensaje'=>'enviado')
```

y en ambos casos me pone route not defined.
Por lo que me pregunto si hay alguna forma de enviar un array y redireccionar a la vez usando controladores restful y que funcione.

Comment: Puedes pegar el código del método store() ?

Comment: Al final lo solucione, tan sencillo como poner la ruta del controlador en el middleware.

Comment: Por favor puedes ser mas explicito, con un ejemplo, te gradecería mucho, sobre: Debes de ponerlo dentro de un grupo middleware.

Answer (score 4):

Bueno yo muestro mis mensajes de la siguiente forma

Primero en el controlador invocamos Session y Redirect

```
Use Session
Use Redirect
```

En tu controlador ya sea en la funcion store, destroy o update

```
Session::flash('message','Your message');
return Redirect::to('/yourroute');
```

Luego en tu vista, muestras el mensaje que definiste en tu controlador

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  {{Session::get('message')}}
</div>
@endif
```

Finalmente, tu ruta que debe de ser algo asi...

```
Route::resource('ruta','MyController')
```

Debes de ponerlo dentro de un grupo middleware.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, funciono a la perfeccion y la respuesta muy descriptiva.

Answer (score 1):

En el método de tu controlador después de hacer tu proceso de inserción puedes responder a tu vista mediante json, por ejemplo:

```
try {
    // lógica para hacer la inserción
    return response()->json(array('status' => 'ok', 'code'=>200, 'message'=>'El registro ha sido guardado'));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    return response()->json(array('status' => 'error', 'code'=>400, 'message'=>$e->getMessage())); //$e->getMessage() sólo para versión en desarrollo, puede cambiarse después por algo como 'Un error ha ocurrido'
}
```

Y desde tu vista hacer una llamada AJAX

```
$('#idBoton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('ruta') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            // otras parametros
        });
    request.done(function(response){
        console.log(response.message);//imprime en consola el resultado
    };
    // si ocurrió un error en el controlador imprimir la excepcion para depurarla
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);// por ejemplo aquí se muestra la excepcion completa como si se tratará de una vista html
);
```

Comment: No habia pensado en hacerlo en json, probaré a ver que tal me va.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Insertar registro nuevo en la tabla funciona bien, pero no me muestra el mensaje. ¿Alguna solución?

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[ 'nombre'=>'required', 'resumen'=>'required', 'npagina'=>'required', 'edicion'=>'required', 'autor'=>'required', 'npagina'=>'required', 'precio'=>'required']);

        Libro::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('libros')->with('success','Registro creado satisfactoriamente');
    }
```